# How to get a logcat using ADB from a sonim xp7 device

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I've been trying to extract a logcat from a sonim xp7 device. I turned on developér options and USB debug, instaled the USB driver for windows and the adb from the android adk both on linux and windows, but in both systems when I type adb devices on the comand line (Already set adb as system variable) the return is nothing even with the device connected (Works for another device samsung s5 and a LG but not with the sonim xp7). Anyone knows how to make the adb work for this device?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score 1):

I just got a Sonim XP7 IS device, and here is how I successfully installed the ADB interface driver on Windows 7 X64:

1. make sure you have got the Google USB driver from Android SDK:

[image: Google USB driver from Android SDK]

2. This is how the phone shows in your device manager:

[image: What the not installed Android phone looks like]

3. Select "Browse my computer for driver software"

[image: Browse my computer for driver software]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9YPR.png)

4. Right click on that exclamation marked device, select Update driver software. And choose "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer". (Ignore the upper half's browsing for driver location stuff)

[image: Let me pick]

5. Select "Have Disk" button:

[image: Choose "Have disk"]

6. You can copy & paste the Google USB driver location here (On my computer it's "C:\android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"), you select "Browse" button and choose the location.

[image: Make sure input correct Google USB location]

7. Now you have some option to choose, please choose "Android Composite ADB Inteface".

[image: Select Android Composite ADB Interface]

8. Probably you got a warning because of compatibility risk. Press "Yes" to confirm.

[image: Update Driver Warning]

9. Now you need to confirm again to install this "Google Inc. Android Phone" device driver.

[image: Confirm installing Google Inc. Android Phone]

10. You have done the driver software installation for: Android Composite ADB Interface.

[image: Android Composite ADB Interface installed]

11. Go back to your device manager and double check the device "Android Composite ADB Interface" is working now.

[image: Android Composite ADB Interface in Device Manager]

12. Now go to command prompt, type "adb start-server", your phone probably will prompt for RSA fingerprint confirmation, remember to select "Yes" otherwise the adb device list will show it as "Unauthenticated".

If you don't see the fingerprint confirmation prompt on the phone, unplug the cable, and plug it again, it should come, double check with "adb devices" in command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Download universal adb driver from the following link

http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://adbdriver.com/&ei=Ho-htPxw&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=853&ts=1435775034&sig=AG8Ucul1mSgYkNHuK-mv8n8xYcMkCw3JOw

Open the driver software, keep ur device connected with system.., and install the driver.

Now close the command prompt, open again and check with adb devices command.

Comment: Tried, the driver software recognizes the android device conected but even after installing and restarting the command prompt and typing adb devices it stills returns nothing. Same results for another computer on windows 8 (The one I used first was 7). Thanks for the tip but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you authenticated your device with the system..?

Comment: The prompt for this doesn't show in the sonim xp7, I believe it is automatic because when I check the system notifications it shows that the usb debug was activated for the current machine connected. When I put a samsung s5 it asks for allowing the debug mode and the same message shows after I click yes,